# Create a complex sphere structure

Tags: modeling

I would like to make a 3d structure of an embryo, something like the one below. It's basically many cells arranged around a sphere. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make that. It doesn't have to be exactly like the one below, but the "cells" or spheres should be of different sizes and connected making a coherent structure.

I would also like to have the ability to change the sizes and numbers of the spheres quickly to make many variations of the embryo, but that's just a bonus.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Embryo:
[image: Embryo]

Comment: something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/41RCL.png

Comment: Yes how did you manage that??

Answer (score 3):

Starting from an ico sphere, with the following modifiers:

[image]

Subdivide (if needed).

Collapse (one or two times). This will add randomness to the mesh. Use triangulate option at the end (for the dual mesh below).

Make a dual mesh using geometry nodes, then extrude a bit the faces. The dual mesh will generate ngons (often hexagons and pentagons).

Subdivide again.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much, I appreciate it, will give it a go!